# Calculating camera angle of view

Tags: python, camera, fieldofview

I know the formula to calculate a camera's angle of view given the film size and the focus distance. I.e., 35mm film at 50mm focal length. It works just fine returning the AOV.

Formula in python:

```
d = 35 # Film Width
f = 50 # Focal Length
aov = 2 * math.atan(float(d) / (2*float(f)))
```

which results in an AOV of 38.58

My question is how would I calculate the Focal Length `f` given the film size `d` and the aov?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [math.se]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the focal length with:

`f = d / (2 * math.tan(0.5 * aov))`

This is derived from the theorem of intersecting lines and the tangents in right-angled triangles:

[image: 1]

*(0.5 * d)/f = a/b = tan(0.5 * aov)*

Comment: Thank you for the reply Stefan. It works. I had forgotten to convert aov to radians but once done, it works. final formula `fl = (d / (2 * math.tan(0.5 * math.radians(aov))))`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that, too. Good you figured it out!